# Android compound component and onclick

Tags: android, custom-component

I have 2 TextViews and an ImageView in a compound component (extending LinearLayout).

I would like the entire component to be clickable, not the individual contained views.

The onClick listener that I set on this compound component is not called, even though there is visual feedback indicating that the component gets touch events.

Any ideas ?

Update: code for my compound component:

```
public class HomeButton extends LinearLayout {
    TextView title;
    TextView subtitle;
    ImageView icon;

    public HomeButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.HomeButton, 0, 0);
        String titleText = a.getString(R.styleable.HomeButton_title);
        String subtitleText = a
                .getString(R.styleable.HomeButton_subtitle);
        int iconResId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.HomeButton_icon, 0);
        a.recycle();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_button, this, true);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_button_title);
        title.setText(titleText);

        subtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_button_subtitle);
        subtitle.setText(subtitleText);
        icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home_button_icon);
        icon.setImageResource(iconResId);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title.setText(title);
    }

    public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
        this.subtitle
                .setVisibility(subtitle == null ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        this.subtitle.setText(subtitle);
    }

}
```

See my own answer below (which I also post here for now as I don't have enough rep to answer my own questions immediately ;))

**Solution, found by myself**

The issue was due to the way my XML layout for the compound component is defined. The root is a LinearLayout.

When inflating the layout in the HomeButton constructor, the view hierarchy does not start at the LinearLayout defined in the XML, it has an extra root node (from the HomeButton class itself I guess), the LinearLayout defined in the XML is the first child of this root node.

Setting the onClick listener on the HomeButton is fine but this is not what is needed in this case, as the onClick events get consumed by the first child node...

Possible solutions from there on:

1. remove the root LinearLayout and use a merge tag
2. override the setOnClickListener to forward to the first child
3. call setClickable(false) on the first child.

I've chosen to go with the 3rd solution (but I've tested that all work) because using a merge tag does not allow to set the style the way I want.

```
public HomeButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.HomeButton, 0, 0);
        String titleText = a.getString(R.styleable.HomeButton_title);
        String subtitleText = a
                .getString(R.styleable.HomeButton_subtitle);
        int iconResId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.HomeButton_icon, 0);
        a.recycle();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_button, this, true);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_button_title);
        title.setText(titleText);

        subtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_button_subtitle);
        subtitle.setText(subtitleText);
        icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home_button_icon);
        icon.setImageResource(iconResId);

            // This made it work
            getChildAt(0).setClickable(false);
    }
```

One thing to be aware of with solution 2: if your onClick listener checks for the id of the view that generated the event, you will not get the id you defined in the XML (because the view that actually generated the event is the first child, not  the HomeButton view), but you can cheat and assign the id of the HomeButton view to that first child...

Comment: Do you have `android:clickable=true` set on the LinearLayout? (or `setClickable(true)`)

Comment: paste your code for more clarity.

Comment: @Keyser I tried adding that both in the XML and in the code, no difference.

Comment: In that case you'll have to provide more info. Setting an onClickListener should work. Does the children have listeners as well? Are those fired?

Comment: @Keyser the children views have no listeners.

Comment: @jbl I'm all out of ideas. Fill your code with debug messages and step through it. That might help you discover weird behavior.

Comment: @Keyser I figured it out, thanks for your time!

Comment: @jbl You should post your answer as an actual answer (I think you have to wait 3 days or so) and accept it. That way other people can easily find your solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove the answer from it, and post the answer as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, found by myself

The issue was due to the way my XML layout for the compound component is defined. The root is a LinearLayout.

When inflating the layout in the HomeButton constructor, the view hierarchy does not start at the LinearLayout defined in the XML, it has an extra root node (from the HomeButton class itself I guess), the LinearLayout defined in the XML is the first child of this root node.

Setting the onClick listener on the HomeButton is fine but this is not what is needed in this case, as the onClick events get consumed by the first child node...

Possible solutions from there on:

1. remove the root LinearLayout and use a merge tag
2. override the setOnClickListener to forward to the first child
3. call setClickable(false) on the first child.

I've chosen to go with the 3rd solution (but I've tested that all work) because using a merge tag does not allow to set the style the way I want.

```
public HomeButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.HomeButton, 0, 0);
    String titleText = a.getString(R.styleable.HomeButton_title);
    String subtitleText = a
            .getString(R.styleable.HomeButton_subtitle);
    int iconResId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.HomeButton_icon, 0);
    a.recycle();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_button, this, true);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_button_title);
    title.setText(titleText);

    subtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_button_subtitle);
    subtitle.setText(subtitleText);
    icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home_button_icon);
    icon.setImageResource(iconResId);

    // This made it work
    getChildAt(0).setClickable(false);
}
```

One thing to be aware of with solution 2: if your onClick listener checks for the id of the view that generated the event, you will not get the id you defined in the XML (because the view that actually generated the event is the first child, not the HomeButton view), but you can cheat and assign the id of the HomeButton view to that first child...

Answer (score 1):

Set the Layout as clickable using the attribute

```
android:clickable=true
```

in your xml, or

```
setClickable(true)
```

to set it programmatically.

You might also want to look at [descendantFocusability](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android%3adescendantFocusability) to determine how clicks on its children will work.

For example:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Gives you: *"The ViewGroup will block its descendants from receiving focus."*

Answer (score -2):

In your activity please check the following.

1. Whether On Click method is getting called.
2. If 1 successful, check if the respective View ID you use in on click method is correct.

Comment: He said that it's not being called.